# Set the layout in the front matter

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a nuxt.js and nuxt/content app that have two different layouts. What I need is to set  the layout inside the markdown files:

`content/blog/hello-world.md`

```
---
layout: 'layout-1'
title: Hello World
---
```

`content/blog/featured-article.md`

```
---
layout: 'featured-layout'
title: Article with special layout
---
```

It's possible?